# CSS animation - position to original place

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I wanted to play with css animation today.

So my basic idea was to create four circle then when user clicks on that circle then it should go to centre of page and then it should become other shape.

So I have used, transform and animation properties.

This is code I have written till now.

```js
$(".circle").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('centerOfPage')){
    $(this).removeClass('centerOfPage');
  }else{
    $(this).addClass('centerOfPage');
  }
});
```

```css
.circle{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
}
.one{
  background-color: red;
}
.two{
  background-color: blue;
}
.three{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.four{
  background-color: green;
}

 .centerOfPage{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation : centerOfPageAnimate 3s;
   
}
@keyframes centerOfPageAnimate {
  0% {
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, 0);    
  }
  100% {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle one"></div>
  <div class="circle two"></div>
  <div class="circle three"></div>
  <div class="circle four"></div>
</div>
```

Now Here there are some problems which you will notice..

- When you click on any circles then their animation will start from top corner not from where they are.
- When you again click on div then they are going back to their position but its not animated, again I want that animation from other shape to circle and on to their same position.

Here is [codepen](http://codepen.io/Nitz/pen/gaLMpx?editors=011) for same.
Thanks.

Comment: Of course it does not “start from where they are”, when you switch elements that weren’t positioned at all before, to `position:fixed` …

Comment: @nitz: Here is what **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)** can do to your animation: **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/pjNReG?editors=001)**. This is just a quick demo, plenty of things can be improved here. But it should give you an idea about GSAP. I know this is not what you asked for, but I thought I should introduce you to it if you weren't already aware.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery I decided to use it 100%. The main difference between my code and yours is that I store each circles position on load and I don't rely on CSS3 keyframes.

I store the circle positions on load by using the jQuery .data method. Now when you remove the 'centerOfPage' class you can revert to the circles previously stored position using jQuery.

See jQuery Snippet and Codepen

```js
$('.circle').each(function () {
  $(this).data('circlePosTop', $(this).position().top);
});
  
$(".circle").click(function(){
 if($(this).hasClass('centerOfPage')){
   $(this).animate({top:$(this).data('circlePosTop'),left:0,borderRadius:'50%',height:'100px',width:'100px'}).removeClass('centerOfPage');
 } else {
   $(this).addClass('centerOfPage').animate({top:0,left:0,borderRadius:'5%',height:'100%',width:'100%'});
 }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyWVyP

Comment: I strongly disagree. JQuery is extremely heavy and should be used as little as possible for this type of visual changes.

Comment: @SofiaFerreira, "extremely heavy" in what sense? jQuery (more specifically, JavaScript) animations have existed since long before CSS animations were ever available. Hardware today is better than hardware "back then" so you could argue that it's less of a concern today than it used to be. The only downside to JavaScript-based animations is that they do not (typically) leverage **hardware acceleration**, which is an optimization you can gain from CSS-based animations.

Answer (score 0):

@nitz JQuery is extremely heavy and it should be used as little as possible for this type of visual changes. You are doing this right.

You need to remove the animation by keyframes, it is more complex.

Please try this:

```js
$(".circle").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("centerOfPage");
});
```

```css
.circle{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 30px;
  
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease .2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease .2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease .2s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease .2s; 
}
.one{
  background-color: red;
  top: 10px;
}
.two{
  background-color: blue;
  top: 120px;
}
.three{
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 230px;
}
.four{
  background-color: green;
  top: 340px;
}

 .centerOfPage{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0; bottom: 0;
   left: 0; right: 0;
   border-radius: 0; 
   z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle one"></div>
  <div class="circle two"></div>
  <div class="circle three"></div>
  <div class="circle four"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you plead for not using jquery for these kind of applications, it would seem logic to me to make the javascript part plain javascript, wouldn't it? It's just a small code after all

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe what you're looking for?

the centerOfPage class is now only there to start the animation, no additional positioning, and using % in the keyframe declaration we can first move it to the center of the page and then make it bigger ( you could also add inbetween steps if you'd like)

```js
$(".circle").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('centerOfPage'); //toggleClass saves you the if else
 });
```

```css
.circle{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 2s linear;  /* added transition to animate going back to start state*/
}
.one{
  background-color: red;
    
}
.two{
  background-color: blue;
}
.three{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.four{
  background-color: green;
}

 .centerOfPage{
   
    animation: test 2s forwards; /* add "forwards" here to stop the animation at end-frame */
  }


  @keyframes test{
   /* You can use percent to target steps during your animation:
      here it moves to the center at 10% animation duration and gets bigger    at 100 % animation duration 
    */
  10%{
  transform: translate(50%);
  }
  100%{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
   border-radius: 5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle one"></div>
  <div class="circle two"></div>
  <div class="circle three"></div>
  <div class="circle four"></div>
</div>
```